# How to make checkboxes dynamic (checked option)

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_model)) {
echo '      <label class="checkbox">
                <input name="model[]" value="'.$row["Model"].'" type="checkbox" checked>'.$row["Model"].'
            </label>
        ';
}
```

I want to make checked option dynamic.
At first I will have all checkboxes checked, but when I will uncheck some checkboxes and click submit, I want to see, after page reloads, whole list with checked and unchecked fields (which I have unchecked formerly). Is it possible to put this option to while statement?
Normally I would do something like that:

```
if ($model == 'My model') {
  echo ' checked';
    } else {
  echo '';
}
```

but in this case I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the value of all the checked checkboxes in a array, let it be `$available`.

Now loop over the query result some what like this -

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_model)) {
  $checked = '';
  if(in_array($row['Model'], $available){
     $checked = 'checked';
   }
     echo '<label class="checkbox">
                <input name="model[]" value="'.$row["Model"].'" type="checkbox" '.$checked.'>'.$row["Model"].'
            </label>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that like as follows :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_model)) {
   if($model == 'My model') { // your condition
       $checked=' checked';
   } else {
       $checked='';
   } 
  echo '<label class="checkbox">';
  echo '
   <input name="model[]" value="'.$row["Model"].'" type="checkbox"'. $checked .'>'.$row["Model"];
  echo  '</label>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like,

```
        if(isset($_POST['model']))
        {
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_model)) 
           {
                if(in_array($_POST,$row['Model'])
                   $checked="checked='checked'";
                else
                   $checked="";

                echo '<label class="checkbox"><input name="model[]" value="'.$row["Model"].'" type="checkbox" '.$checked.'>'.$row["Model"].'</label>';
           }            

        }
        else{
             while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_model)) 
             {
                  echo '<label class="checkbox"><input name="model[]" value="'.$row["Model"].'" type="checkbox"   checked>'.$row["Model"].'</label>';
             }
        }
```